# Setting focus to an input after changing display to "block"

Tags: javascript

I cant find the answer to this within a search.

Using javascript I have a div (ac) with an onclick event part of which is to set focus to an input element (gn) within a previously hidden div (as).

I would expect this to work:

```
ac.onmousedown = function () {
    csect.style.display = "none";
    as.style.display = "block";
    gn.focus();
}
```

but didn't, so I added small delay

```
ac.onmousedown = function () {
    csect.style.display = "none";
    as.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){
        gn.focus()
        },30);
}
```

which made it work.

Is this delay really necessary? Have I missed something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting focus on an input element after setting display:block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401245/setting-focus-on-an-input-element-after-setting-displayblock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default action of the click (setting the focus to the thing you clicked on) takes place *after* the *mousedown* event handler has fired. This means that the JavaScript sets the focus to `gn` and then the normal behaviour of clicking on `ac` sets the focus to `ac`.

See [this example](http://jsbin.com/ufecok/2/edit) for a demonstration.

Use a *click* event instead of a *mousedown* event.

Comment: Thanks - helped my understanding a lot.